# vba large if statement based on a lot of comparables, any smarter way to do it?

Tags: vba, if-statement, optimization

i have a rather large code, which started small but as the variables kept coming so did the code.

my first "problem" is this part:

```
If (Cells(k, 5) = buafd1 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd2 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd3 _
Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd4 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd5 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd6 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd7 _
Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd8 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd9 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd10 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd11 _
Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd12 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd13) And Cells(k, 6) = LCSPnavn1 Then

                    Amount = Cells(k, 13)
                    LCSPsum1 = LCSPsum1 + Amount
```

as you can see the cell that i look at is the same, but i am checking it against a list of variables which is a criteria for the sum function to be activated

the next thing is that i have alot of "LCSPsums"

```
like this:

'LCSPsum 2

                ElseIf (Cells(k, 5) = buafd1 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd2 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd3 _
Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd4 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd5 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd6 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd7 _
Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd8 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd9 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd10 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd11 _
Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd12 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd13) And Cells(k, 6) = LCSPnavn2 Then

                    Amount = Cells(k, 13)
                    LCSPsum2 = LCSPsum2 + Amount

'LCSPsum 3
                ElseIf (Cells(k, 5) = buafd1 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd2 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd3 _
Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd4 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd5 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd6 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd7 _
Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd8 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd9 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd10 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd11 _
Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd12 Or Cells(k, 5) = buafd13) And Cells(k, 6) = LCSPnavn3 Then

                    Amount = Cells(k, 13)
                    LCSPsum3 = LCSPsum3 + Amount
```

all the way to 28 xD

it is working but i am now trying to put more "buafd" on which is a pretty slow process since i have to add 7 times "cells(k,5) = buafd..." 28 times.

Does someone have a smart solution that might also make it work faster?

regards
Niklas

Answer (score 1):

First I would put your variables in an array.  This way when you need to increase the number of these variables you can just increase the size of your array.

```
Dim oBuafd(12) As String
Dim oLCSPnavn(27) As Double
Dim oLCSPsum(27) As Double  ' or you could do a multi-dimensional array with oLCSPnavn
```

Function to search array and return true if it found the value

```
Private Function InList(ByVal SearchValue As String, ByRef List() As String) As Boolean
    InList = False

    Dim oCounter As Integer
    For oCounter = 0 To UBound(List)
        If StrComp(SearchValue, List(oCounter), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            InList = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This would be the code to replace all your repeated steps.  If amount is just being used at this point and serves no other function then you don't need it, you can apply the amount directly to oLCSPnavn.

```
Dim Amount As Double
Dim oCounter As Integer
For oCounter = 0 To UBound(oLCSPnavn)
    If InList(Sheet1.Cells(11, 5), oBuafd) And oLCSPnavn(oCounter) = Sheet1.Cells(11, 6) Then
        Amount = Sheet1.Cells(11, 13)
        oLCSPsum(oCounter) = oLCSPsum(oCounter) + Amount ' Is this all your doing with amount or does it have another purpose?
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Edit: Missed oLCSPsum array, originally read it as oLCSPnavn.  Added declaration for sum, as well as put it in the appropriate location in the code,

Comment: Hi again

so first problem is when i declare the variables like: 
Dim LCSPnavn(1 to 100) as string

and then try to set it like this:
        LCSPnavn1 = Cells(i, 12)

then i get error Variable not defined, what to do ?

Comment: @NiklasBorkPetersen It would be LCSPnavn(1) = Cells(i,12).  Here's a short article on [Excel Arrays](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html).  Also Note: if your starting your array indexes at 1, you'll need to update the counters to start their as well.